# Entity framework trunk json size to 65535

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My website is developed using asp net core 2, connected to a mysql database 5.7.25 in Ubuntu 16.04 through Entity framework 6.2.0. Data base connected through mysql.data.entityframeworkcore 6.10.6.

One column is defined as json. The Entity Framework defined as

```
entity.Property(e => e.PlotFeature)
                    .HasColumnName("plot_feature")
                    .HasColumnType("json");
```

Then the json string is trunk into 65535 character if data is posted and put through Entity Framework.

My current solution is to change the column type into mediumtext.

But I still want to use json as the column type. Is there any ways to change the constrain of json in Entity Framework?

Comment: Which provider did you use? MySQL's own Connector.NET treats JSON as a MySqlString. Other providers like [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) and [MySqlConnectr](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) may not have that limitation

Comment: I am using mysql.data.entityframeworkcore 6.10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/) nuget is used. Then Json column is limited to 65535 because MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore (at least v 8.0.15) maps it to VARCHAR db type, which is limited to 65k.

From [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535.

Comment: That's a limitation of MySQL's Connector, not the EF provider. This means that even plain ADO.NET would have the same issue as long as that connector is used

Comment: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore inside has json->varchar map as well, thus it might be that json is being passed to MySQL Connector as varchar in this case

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It makes sense now.